# Are the "GONE" views inflated?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a huge XML layout, with many `Relative / Linear` layouts, and what I'm doing now is to hide all the layouts I don't need with `setVisibility (View.GONE)` and change their visibility when needed.

My question is : is this method sufficient? are the layouts inflated and rendered so they alter the phone memory and it's performances and time of the activity loading or they are not until I set the visibility to `VISIBLE`.

The layout is getting bigger so I would like to know if I should use `Fragments` or stay with what I have now.

Comment: if those were not how could you change their visibilty?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> are the layouts inflated

Yes.

> and rendered

No. They are part of the view hierarchy but are ignored in the rendering passes.

Comment: Very rightly put. :) Just to add a little to above, **ignored in the rendering passes** means they are there in the layout (exists) but Invisible and do not take any space either. :)

Comment: Thank you. Since they're inflated, the performances of the phone are altered right ? or are they only when the layouts are rendered ?

Comment: @Mehdi: "Since they're inflated, the performances of the phone are altered right ?" -- I do not know what "performances" concern you. `GONE` widgets and containers take up heap space like regular widgets. They are ignored in the rendering passes, so they will not consume much in the way of CPU time, and they should take no GPU time.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: Basically this means `onMeasure`, `onLayout`, and `onDraw` won't get called for the GONE view and it's children.